# Getting flex datagrid cell value using column and row indices

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, row, recovery

i'm using flex for an application but i'm having some trouble to recover data from a  datagrid that has a checkbox in one of the columns, the problem is that i can't use the function selectedIndex or selectedItem, because they are used to save the checked items.

Is there a way to recovery the datagrid informations using the column and row indices? Something like:

MyDataGrid[row][column] or MyDataProvider[row][column] or any combination of functions to allow me recovery an information using only the row and column.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code that exhibits the problem? I'm afraid I'm not understanding your question. There are several data grid components in Flex, so we don't know which one you're talking about. There is a [GridEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/GridEvent.html) that has row/column information, but it's difficult to say if it will help you.

Comment: DataGrid only accepts DataProviders that implement IList. IList has a method called getItemAt. This will give you the row (aka the object in the list that is displayed in that row). The column can be determined by parsing the DataGrid structure. But there is something that bother me, how did you code that? It seems that you're not using DataGrid, Renderer and stuff in the proper way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to be able to get a cell value of the data grid using row and col indices, you can extend the DataGrid component and add one simple function.

Here is a [working example](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/dggetrc/index.html).

It looks something like this:

//CustomDataGrid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:DataGrid xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
        width="400" height="300">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;

        public function getElementAt(row:int, col:int):Object
        {
            if (this.dataProvider.length < row + 1 || this.columns.length < col + 1)
                return null;
            else
                return this.dataProvider.getItemAt(row)[(this.columns.getItemAt(col) as GridColumn).dataField];
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Then you call it in your application like this:

//App

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
           xmlns:dgrc="com.dgrc.*">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        [Bindable]private var collection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {fld01:1, fld02:"fld02", fld03:"fld13", fld04:"fld14"},
            {fld01:2, fld02:"fld02", fld03:"fld23", fld04:"fld24"},
            {fld01:3, fld02:"fld02", fld03:"fld33", fld04:"fld34"},
            {fld01:4, fld02:"fld02", fld03:"fld43", fld04:"fld44"},
            {fld01:5, fld02:"fld02", fld03:"fld53", fld04:"fld54"}
        ]);

        protected function getElement():void
        {
            var obj:Object = myDG.getElementAt(nsRow.value, nsCol.value);
            Alert.show(String(obj));
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup x="20" y="20">

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:NumericStepper id="nsRow" minimum="0" value="0"/>
        <s:NumericStepper id="nsCol" minimum="0" value="0"/>
        <s:Button label="Get It!" click="getElement()"/>
    </s:HGroup>

    <dgrc:CustomDataGrid id="myDG" width="300" height="160" dataProvider="{collection}">
        <dgrc:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>  
                <s:GridColumn dataField="fld01" headerText="Field 1" width="100"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="fld03" headerText="Field 3" width="100"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="fld04" headerText="Field 4"/>
            </s:ArrayList>                  
        </dgrc:columns> 
    </dgrc:CustomDataGrid>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Be aware that the row and col indices in this example refer a cell of the data grid and not a value of the data grid provider.

If you call

```
getElementAt(0, 1)
```

you will get "fld13"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the original DataGrid control, it is better to use the `itemToLabel` method of `DataGridColumn`, because `item[dataField]` will cause an exception when the property value contains dot notation, such as `"customer.name"`:

```
    public function getElementAt(row:int, col:int):Object {
        var item:Object = dataProvider.getItemAt(row)
        var column:DataGridColumn = dataGrid.columns[column] as DataGridColumn;
        var value:String = column.itemToLabel(item);
        return value;
    }
```

This same method is used by the framework to provide the text displayed in the grid cell.  If your checkbox in the grid is driven by a boolean property, the returned value will be `true` or `false`.